# Response time of a relay

Tags: relay

Some customers ask me about the response time of a relay, But inside the catalogue,two different delays are mentioned: the switch-on and the switch-off delays of the relay. which of these two delays are determinative of the relay response time?

you can check switch-on and switch-off delay in output section:
http://catalog.weidmueller.com/procat/Product.jsp;jsessionid=BCE8FA0695A52E7BE6D7EC63694D5B03?productId=(%5b1381900000%5d)&page=Productue

Comment: If the customer doesn't care about the distinction, just give them the larger of the two numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A relay has two different times, the switch-on and the switch-off. In some circumstances, one is more important than the other, so you have to specify which.

If the customers don't know or care about which they are asking about, then you take the larger, and quote it as the 'worst case'.

Answer (score 3):

Hi @MINA "On time" depends on voltage <=5ms (nom) while **"off time" <=15ms** depends on spring-force *PLUS* quench-time of arc. **Both are important.**

Perhaps, Ask customers what does it need to be?

Lowering coil current causes Relays to take longer to activate.

Quenching of arcs currents^2 * ESR * time =Energy = kT temperature rise, thus erodes useful lifetime operations and depends on customer application.

Compare with Omron who are the best IMHO. They have OFF times such as 5 ms which makes it more reliable.

Also compare contact materials and bipolar coil response times which are faster.